# Unable to set Azure autoscale formula using HTTP API

Tags: python, azure, azure-aks, azure-batch

Here goes my first question in SO. It's related with `Azure` and the way we can set the autoscale formula using the `HTTP API`.

I have followed [Authenticate Requests to Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/authenticate-requests-to-the-azure-batch-service) docs and created the `StringToSing`. It looks like this:

```
POST\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
application/json;odata=minimalmetadata\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
ocp-date:Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:02:22 GMT\n
/myaccountname/pools/scalingpool/enableautoscale\n
api-version:2020-09-01.12.0\n
timeout:30\n
```

Of course, my batch account name **is not** `myaccountname`. I just used this value on this post. On the console I'm using the real account name.

The whole string I pasted above is hashed together with the corresponding Secret Key, and the result is `base64` encoded.

Thus, considering that my Secret Key is stored on variable secretKey. I use the following Python code to create the `base64` string (as you can see, it prints the `base64` string on the screen):

```
signature = hmac.new(secretKey.encode('utf-8'),data.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256) 
byteSignature = signature.digest()
b64Signature = base64.b64encode(byteSignature)
print (b64Signature.decode('ascii'))
```

Once the `base64` is generated, I use it to create the Authorization header. I put everything together this way:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: SharedKey myaccountname:BASE64_STRING" -H "Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata" -H "ocp-date:Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:20:12 GMT" --data @autoscaling_pool_scalingpool.json "https://myaccountname.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com/pools/scalingpool/enableautoscale?timeout=30&api-version=2020-09-01.12.0"
```

Where:

1. `BASE64_STRING` is the base64 string previously generated
2. `autoscaling_pool_scalingpool.json` is file storing my autoscale formula
3. `scalingpool` is the name of the node pool in my Kubernetes cluster, that I want to enable autoscale.

Unfortunately, this is the result:

```
*  subject: C=US; ST=WA; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; CN=*.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com
*  start date: Nov 14 04:33:26 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  9 04:33:26 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "myaccountname.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com" matched cert's "*.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Microsoft Corporation; CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 05
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55b584497920)
> POST /pools/scalingpool/enableautoscale?timeout=30&api-version=2020-09-01.12.0 HTTP/2
> Host: myaccountname.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com
> user-agent: curl/7.72.0
> accept: */*
> authorization: SharedKey myaccountname:BASE64_STRING
> content-type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
> ocp-date:Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:20:12 GMT
> content-length: 237
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 403 
< content-length: 906
< content-type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
< server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< request-id: a9b609a2-4b15-453d-904c-b0fc588527a0
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< dataserviceversion: 3.0
< date: Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:22:44 GMT
< 
{
  "odata.metadata":"https://myaccountname.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{
    "lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:a9b609a2-4b15-453d-904c-b0fc588527a0\nTime:2020-12-30T13:22:44.1054663Z"
  },"values":[
    {
      "key":"AuthenticationErrorDetail","value":"The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'BASE64_STRING' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'POST\n\n\n237\n\napplication/json;odata=minimalmetadata\n\n\n\n\n\n\nocp-date:Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:20:12 GMT\n/myaccountname/pools/scalingpool/enableautoscale\napi-version:2020-09-01.12.0\ntimeout:30'."
    }
  ]
* Connection #0 to host myaccountname.germanywestcentral.batch.azure.com left intact
}
```

As you can see, I can't get the authentication working. What really tricks me is the value for the key `AuthenticationErrorDetail`, in the response. It includes the string I used to sing my request, but it looks a little bit different:

`POST\n\n\n237\n\napplication/json;odata=minimalmetadata\n\n\n\n\n\n\nocp-date:Wed, 30 Dec 2020 13:20:12 GMT\n/myaccountname/pools/scalingpool/enableautoscale\napi-version:2020-09-01.12.0\ntimeout:30`

After POST method we should have only 5 times "\n". However, there's a `237` number! I'm absolutely sure that I didn't include this number on the string to be signed. Besides, I can't figure out what it means.

I found some examples in C# and .Net, but I don't want to use it. As far as I know, these examples create the string to be signed in the same format.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

I could get the code suggested below by Stanley Gong. However, the overall solution is not what I was expecting.

I'm aware of Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and Cluster Autoscaler. Nevertheless, and don't want to scale up/down nodes because deployments/pods are not running, or because system metrics (CPU, memory, etc) says so.

Given the examples I found on Internet, the batch account thing, together with a scaling formular were what suited my needs. As I posted in this post, I want to keep machines runnings during workings days/hours.

Right now I have the cluster, a resource group (`rg1`) and a batch account. The batch account belongs to the resource group `rg2`. But the cluster seems to belong to the resource group `rg2`.

I'll keep digging more on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python and you want to set pool autoscale formulas, using Azure batch python SDK will be much easier than generating Authorization headers and make HTTP requests.

Try code below:

```
import azure.batch._batch_service_client as batch
import azure.batch.batch_auth as batchauth

batch_url= '<batch service url>'
batch_account = '<account name>'
pool_id = '<id of pool you want to set formula>'
key = '<account key>'

creds = batchauth.SharedKeyCredentials(batch_account, key)
batch_client = batch.BatchServiceClient(
        creds,
        batch_url=batch_url)

myAutoScaleFormula = "$TargetDedicatedNodes = (time().weekday == 1 ? 5:1);"

batch_client.pool.enable_auto_scale(pool_id=pool_id,auto_scale_formula=myAutoScaleFormula)
```

Result:

[image]

You can find more sample codes about Azure batch SDK for Python [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/Python/Batch).

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. To be honest, AKS is not the first Cloud provider I could get signed requests working. At the end, they all explain you how to get things done, but things only get "really" done if you rely in some SDK. I applied your code and now got stuck on a new error: `Message: {'additional_properties': {}, 'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'The specified pool does not exist.\nRequestId:<REQUEST_ID>\nTime:<TIMESTAMP>'`

Comment: This comment is here to clarify the last one. It turns out that the node pool my batch account was trying to control, is not the node pool I want to be controlled. There's an update on the initial message on this post giving more details on this.